# Javascript setTimeout is returning my function parameter value as undefined

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

Please refer to my below code:

```js
//Principal Function
function greet3(name, sayName) {
  document.getElementById("jac3").innerHTML = "Hello " + name;
  sayName(name);
};
//Callback Function

function sayName(name) {
  document.getElementById("jac3").innerHTML += ". How are you? " + name;
}
//Calling the function after 10 seconds

greet3("Neha", setTimeout(sayName,3000));
//greet3("Neha", sayName);
```

```html
<p id="jac3"></p>
```

When I use `setTimeout` function,

```
greet3("Neha", setTimeout(sayName,3000));
```

the output of name gets `undefined`.

Please help me with correct syntax.

Answer (score 3):

When you write setTimeout(param1, param2) you are executing the function due to the parenthesis.

```js
//Principal Function
function greet3(name, callback, timeout) {
  document.getElementById("jac3").innerHTML = "Hello " + name;
  setTimeout(() => callback(name), timeout);
};

//Callback Function
function sayName(name) {
  document.getElementById("jac3").innerHTML += ". How are you? " + name;
}

//Calling the function after 3 seconds
greet3("Neha", sayName, 3000);
```

```html
<p id="jac3"></p>
```